# Remove files from Netbeans project, but not from hard drive

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

In my project folder a lot of files, but I don't want have them all in my Netbeans project.
Also Netbeans scanning them automatically using more memory and time.

Is there a way to exclude files/folders from Netbeans project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution working with Netbeans 7.3:

- right click on your project in the "Projects" window,
- click on "Properties",
- click on "Ignored folders" in the left panel called "Categories",
- click on "Add folder" and select the folders you want to ignore.

Comment: I'm using NB 7.3 RC1, I can't find this option. What version you are using?

Comment: My version is NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201302132200).

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to unwanted projects in the dropdown menu or unwanted files in one project? And which files specifically are you referring to? If it is useless in the project, you could just delete the file, although if it comes with the project, I would be careful since most of those are required in the project. If you are referring to other projects in the project dropdown menu, you could always put the projects that you have finished in another folder.

Comment: I'm referring to unwanted files in the project. But these files should be present in project folder on disk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need most of these files as a part of Netbeans for compiling. Everything in the src, nbproject, and build folders are needed for your program. So no, I don't think it's possible to delete anything within those folders without deleting an essential part of your Netbeans project.