# How to make Netbeans remove deleted files from the project?

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake, makefile

I am developing a C++ program using CMake as a Makefile generator. I have added the project as an existing source to the Netbeans and everything works nice except when I update lists of dependencies for my build targets.

Netbeans is able to get the new files added to the project, but keeps removed files hanging with a small yellow warning icon in the list of files. So the only way they could be removed is to manually in the GUI or by removing them from configurations.xml in the project.

As far as I understand the issue is about the way Netbeans scans for external changes. Is there a way to tell it to remove deleted files from the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750433/remove-files-from-netbeans-project-but-not-from-hard-drive):

```
right click on your project in the "Projects" window,
click on "Properties",
click on "Ignored folders" in the left panel called "Categories",
click on "Add folder" and select the folders you want to ignore.
```

You can also clear the cache located in:

```
C:\Users\username\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache. //Deleting this directory should clear the cache for you.
```

Comment: Clearing the cache doesn't help here.

Comment: And I do not want to ignore folders or files. E.g. I have an included file a.cpp and rename it externally to c.cpp. Netbeans scans these external changes and now in the project I have both of them - working c.cpp and hanging with yellow sign obsolete a.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a file name with no file from my C++ static library project...

< File < OpenProject < "YourProject"   (< means left click)  (Leads To Projects.)

< Source Files > a.cpp < Remove File From Project  (> means right click)

< Header Files > a.h < Remove File From Project    (And the header file.)

I'm using netbeans 8.2.  Curiously only c.cpp is listed under "Source files". 
And only c.h is listed under "Header Files". 
All the other (actual, real) source and header files are listed under "Important Files".